# How to split alphabetic strings by dot using regex?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'd like to split strings by `.` if the other characters are alphabetic only and the string doesn't start or end with `.`.

So the expected result for `abc.def.xyz` would be `[abc,def,xyz]`.

The following string should be left as they are:
`abc.`
`xy.a3`
`1a.ab`
`abc.def,xyz`

Basically I'm looking for a more elegant solution to the my current code:

```
if(canSplit(x)){
   var parts = x.split("\\.");
   ...
}

boolean canSplit(String text) {
    if(text.startsWith(".") || text.endsWith(".")) return false;
    
    for(var s : text.split("\\.")) {
        for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if(!Character.isAlphabetic(s.charAt(i))) return false;
        }
    }
    return true;        
}
```

Comment: I would prefer maximally readable code over "elegance". From [that perspective](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/javase/devinsight-1.html), this code appears fine. Perhaps `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]+", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);` before the loop and replace the inner loop with `if (!p.matcher(s).matches()) { return false; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with your aproach. But if you want to use regex, your `canSplit` method could look like :

```
boolean canSplit(String text) {
    String regex = "[a-z]+(?:\\.[a-z]+)+";
    return text.matches(regex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex and grab captured group #1

```
(?:^(?=\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+)+$)|(?!^)\G\.)(\p{L}+)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/POQD7x/1)

**Details:**

- `(?=\p{L}+(?:\.\p{L}+)+$)` ensures we have dot separated alphabets only in a line
- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `(?!^)` ensures that we don't allow `\G` to match at the start

**Java Code:**

```
jshell> String str = "abc.def.xyz";
str ==> "abc.def.xyz"

jshell> String re = "(?:^(?=\\p{L}+(?:\\.\\p{L}+)+$)|(?!^)\\G\\.)(\\p{L}+)";
re ==> "(?:^(?=\\p{L}+(?:\\.\\p{L}+)+$)|(?!^)\\G\\.)(\\p{L}+)"

jshell> Pattern.compile(re, Pattern.MULTILINE).matcher(str).results().flatMap(mr -> IntStream.rangeClosed(1, mr.groupCount()).mapToObj(mr::group)).collect(Collectors.toList());
$6 ==> [abc, def, xyz]
```